# List all possible words with n letters

Tags: python

I want to list all possible words with n letters where the first letter can be a1 or a2, the second can be b1, b2 or b3, the third can be c1 or c2, ... Here's a simple example input-output for n=2 with each letter having 2 alternatives:

- input = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
- output = ["ac", "ad", "bc", "bd"]

I tried doing this recursively by creating all possible words with the first 2 letters first, so something like this:

```
def go(l):
    if len(l) > 2:
        head = go(l[0:2])
        tail = l[2:]
        tail.insert(0, head)
        go(tail)
    elif len(l) == 2:
        res = []
        for i in l[0]:
            for j in l[1]:
                res.append(i+j)
        return res
    elif len(l) == 1:
        return l
    else:
        return None
```

However, this becomes incredibly slow for large n or many alternatives per letter. What would be a more efficient way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean word as in dictionary word, or just an arbitrary arrangement of letters?

Comment: Do you need the results to be stored in a list, or is it okay just to print them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just want [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) here:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lst = ['ab', 'c', 'de']
>>> words = product(*lst)
>>> list(words)
[('a', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'e')]`
```

Or, if you wanted them joined into words:

```
>>> [''.join(word) for word in product(*lst)]
['acd', 'ace', 'bcd', 'bce']
```

Or, with your example:

```
>>> lst = [["a","b"],["c","d"]]
>>> [''.join(word) for word in product(*lst)]
['ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd']
```

---

Of course for very large `n` or very large sets of letters (size `m`), this *will* be slow. If you want to generate an exponentially large set of outputs (`O(m**n)`), that will take exponential time. But at least it has constant rather than exponential space (it generates one product at a time, instead of a giant list of all of them), and will be faster than what you were on your way to by a decent constant factor, and it's a whole lot simpler and harder to get wrong.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  It specifically stated that the first letter must be chosen from a specific group of letters, the second letter must be chosen from a second group, the third letter must be chosen from a third group, etc.

Comment: Check the output carefully, this does exactly that.

Comment: @JohnGordon The first letter is chosen from the group `'ab'`, the second from the group `'c'`, the third from the group `'de'`.

Comment: My mistake!  That will teach me to read more carefully.  I think some of the other answers do have this issue though.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, vidstige's answer does have that problem, and C Perforrmance's answer would have that problem if it didn't have a bigger one that got in the way.

Comment: Cool, looks like I was reinventing the wheel... Great answer, thanks!

Comment: In fact, I want to create this list and then pick a number of its elements at random. I guess the only way to speed this up is to pick the right number of alternatives first and then generate the list.

Comment: Alternative to list comprehension: `list(map(''.join, product(*input)))`

Comment: @niefpaarschoenen I don't know how many you're looking to pick and how you're looking to distribute them, but yes, filtering the groups with `random.sample` or `letter for letter in group if random.random() > q` or whatever _before_ the `product` will be hugely faster, even if it may (depending on what you want to do) be more complicated.

Comment: @AGNGazer Sure, but why? If I don't want a list, and I already have a function/method/partial lying around to map, I usually use `map` over a genexpr. But otherwise, it's usually less readable, not more.

Comment: I find `map` more readable. I agree with you with regard to `list` (I added it to get the "final result").

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) from the built-in itertools module to achieve this, like so

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> [''.join(word) for word in permutations('abc', 2)]
['ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb']
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants. They want the first character to be chosen from a1 or a2; the second from b1, b2, or b3; the third from c1 or c2; etc.

Comment: yes, you're right. Answer by @abarnert is the right one

Answer (score -1):

## Generating all strings of some length with given alphabet :

test.py :

```
def generate_random_list(alphabet, length):
    if length == 0: return []
    c = [[a] for a in alphabet[:]]
    if length == 1: return c
    c = [[x,y] for x in alphabet for y in alphabet]
    if length == 2: return c
    for l in range(2, length):
        c = [[x]+y for x in alphabet for y in c]
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for p in generate_random_list(['h','i'],2):
        print p
```

---

### $ python2 test.py

```
['h', 'h']
['h', 'i']
['i', 'h']
['i', 'i']
```

---

## Next Way :

```
def generate_random_list(alphabet, length):
    c = []
    for i in range(length):
        c = [[x]+y for x in alphabet for y in c or [[]]]
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for p in generate_random_list(['h','i'],2):
        print p
```

## Next Way :

```
import itertools
if __name__ == "__main__":
    chars = "hi"
    count = 2
    for item in itertools.product(chars, repeat=count):
        print("".join(item))
```

---

```
import itertools
print([''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('hi',repeat=2)])
```

## Next Way :

```
from itertools import product
#from string import ascii_letters, digits

#for i in product(ascii_letters + digits, repeat=2):
for i in product("hi",repeat=2):
    print(''.join(i))
```

Comment: The OP wants to generate _all_ of the products. Generating them randomly is not a good way to do that. Also, you're using the same set for each letter, instead of one set for the first, a different one for the second, etc.